# Using InputBox to return user input as a text string as a variable in a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to take user input and insert it in a formula.

The input box would have a field for account name, month, type.

This variable would need to be returned in the `sumifs` formula saying `sumifs`, `column E` is this account `column c` is this month and `column d` is this type.

I've looked but all I find involve `numbers inputs` much less returning the `text string` as a variable in a `sumifs` formula.

Formula Ex:

`=SUMIFS(E2:E100, A2:A100, "Account Name",C2:C100,"Month",D2:D100,"Type")`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to build a form if you want to have the three input boxes on one form.  If you can live with three separate input forms you can do it like this.

```
Dim AccountName As Variant 
AccountName = InputBox("Please Enter the account name.*", "Account Name")
Dim AccountMonth As Variant 
AccountMonth = InputBox("Please Enter the account name.*", "Account Date")
Dim AccountType As Variant 
AccountType = InputBox("Please Enter the account name.*", "Account Type")
```

You will want to put some validations on the values that are entered.

Then you can use them to build you formula

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

ws.Range("A2").Formula = "=sumifs(E2:E100, A2:A100, " & AccountName & ",C2:C100," & AccountMonth  & ",D2:D100," & AccountMonth & ")"
```

You will need to target the cell you want to write the formula into.  I used A2 because I didn't know your target cell.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Great flow of instruction thank you.